# Add Azure Traffic Manager endpoints in main bicep template as child resource

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-traffic-manager, azure-bicep

I'm trying to add a new Traffic Manager Profile via a `Network/trafficManagerProfiles.bicep` module which I invoke in my `main.bicep` file.
This works well.

The `main.bicep` file is creating multiple Function Apps using their own little module, which is invoked similar like this

```
module functionAppModule 'Web/functions.bicep' = {
  dependsOn: [
    appServicePlanModule
    webApiStorageAccount
  ]
  name: 'functionAppModule'
  params: {
    environmentName: environmentName
    systemName: systemName
    azureRegion: azureRegion
    appServicePlanId: appServicePlanModule.outputs.id
  }
}
```

Now I'm trying to add the necessary endpoints of my web applications (Azure Functions) to the Traffic Manager Profile, which is also possible by [using the `endpoints` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.network/trafficmanagerprofiles?tabs=bicep&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003246).

However, this would mean I need to add a parameter to this file accepting an array of objects containing all information about my App Services, or I would need to resolve them over here (by retrieving the instances with the `existing` keyword). This doesn't sound like the way to implement this, because all those resources are already available/referenced in the `main.bicep` file.

The Traffic Manager Profile module now looks like this:

```
param systemName string
@allowed([
  'dev'
  'test'
  'acc'
  'prod'
])
param environmentName string
param relativeLiveEndpoint string = '/api/Live'

var trafficManagerProfileName = '${systemName}${environmentName}'

resource trafficManagerProfile 'Microsoft.Network/trafficmanagerprofiles@2018-08-01' = {
  name: trafficManagerProfileName
  location: 'global'
  properties: {
    allowedEndpointRecordTypes: [
      'DomainName'
    ]
    dnsConfig: {
      relativeName: trafficManagerProfileName
      ttl: 60
    }
    profileStatus: 'Enabled'
    trafficRoutingMethod: 'Performance'
    monitorConfig: {
      profileMonitorStatus: 'Online'
      protocol: 'HTTPS'
      port: 443
      path: relativeLiveEndpoint
      timeoutInSeconds: 10
      intervalInSeconds: 30
      toleratedNumberOfFailures: 3
    }
    endpoints: [
      {
        id: 'the resource id'
        name: 'the resource name'
        type: 'the resource type'
        properties: {
          endpointStatus: 'Enabled'
          endpointMonitorStatus: 'Online'
          targetResourceId: 'the resource id'
          target: 'mysite.azurewebsites.net'
          endpointLocation: 'West Europe'
          weight: 1
          priority: 1
        }
      }
      // All other app services
    ]
  }
}
```

According to some answers here on Stack Overflow, the `endpoints` can also be created via a child resource in ARM templates (something like `Microsoft.Network/trafficmanagerprofiles/endpoints`), however, this doesn't appear to be available in Bicep (or just isn't available in the autocomplete).

What I'd like to do is something like this in my `main.bicep` file, because that way I can reference all App Services I want to add.

```
var trafficManagerProfileEndpoints 'Microsoft.Network/trafficmanagerprofiles/endpoints@2050-01-01` = {
  name: '${trafficManagerProfile.Name}/endpoints'
  endpoints: [ 
    // All of my endpoints
  ]
}
```

Somewhat similar compared to what's available via `Microsoft.Web/sites/config@2020-12-01` for configuration settings in an App Service.

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible through Bicep ARM but the `Microsoft.Network/trafficManagerProfiles` api doesn't have types available for endpoints so it will generate a warning even if the deployment works perfectly.

If you define a traffic manager profile without the `endpoints` property:

```bicep
resource trafficManager 'Microsoft.Network/trafficmanagerprofiles@2018-08-01' = {
  name: '<name>'
  location: 'global'
  properties: {
    profileStatus: 'Enabled'
    trafficRoutingMethod: '<trafficRoutingMethod>'
    dnsConfig: {
      ...
    }
    monitorConfig: {
      ...
    }    
  }
}
```

You can then add endpoints like that:

```bicep
// Azure endpoints: cloud service, app service, app service slots, public ip
resource trafficManagerAzureEndpoint 'Microsoft.Network/trafficManagerProfiles/azureEndpoints@2018-08-01' = {
  name: name
  parent: trafficManager 
  properties: {
    ...
  }
}

// External endpoint
resource trafficManagerExternalEndpoint 'Microsoft.Network/trafficManagerProfiles/externalEndpoints@2018-08-01' = {
  name: name
  parent: trafficManager 
  properties: {
    ...
  }
}

// Nested endpoints
resource trafficManagerNestedEndpoint 'Microsoft.Network/trafficManagerProfiles/nestedEndpoints@2018-08-01' = {
  name: name
  parent: trafficManager 
  properties: {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks exactly what I was looking for! Will try it out later this week.

Comment: Just as you suggested, this worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I just ran through your question at lightning speed, forgive me if I don't fully understand it, but it looks like you need to declare your web app as a resource again, but as existing. This allows you to access all the props you need from your app service.

This blog explains how to use existing resources in Bicep: https://hexmaster.nl/posts/bicep-existing/

Comment: Thanks, this has indeed crossed my mind (I've added an inline comment on this in the answer) but doesn't 'feel' like the way to implement this.